# Lookup-id-control in WPF DataGrid

Tags: wpf

I am working with DataGrid. One column displays text, but the data behind this contains only an id. This id must somehow be converted to a string.

I need something like a combobox with the properties *ItemsSource*, *DisplayMemberPath*, *SelectedValue* and *SelectedValuePath*. But instead of a button displayed, there must be only a text. Is there some control for that?

That works (would like to exchange combobox with something that looks like textbox):

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Leistungsart" MinWidth="100">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox   ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=viewModel}, Path=Leistungsarten}"                                      
                                        DisplayMemberPath="Bezeichnung"
                                        SelectedValue="{Binding Path=BDELeistungsartID, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=NullableInt2IntConverter}}"
                                        SelectedValuePath="BDELeistungsartID"
                                        IsEnabled="false"
                                        IsEditable="False"
                                        Height="35">                                
  </ComboBox>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a ComboBox, but overwrite the Template property to show just a Label. You'll have to recreate the Click events too.

Easiest way would be to use a tool like Snoop or Blend and see what the default ComboBox template looks like, and modify that to what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks a lot for your aswer. Yes, that with Template property worked for me:

```
<ComboBox   ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=viewModel}, Path=Leistungsarten}"                                      
                                    DisplayMemberPath="Bezeichnung"
                                    SelectedValue="{Binding Path=BDELeistungsartID, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=NullableInt2IntConverter}}"
                                    SelectedValuePath="BDELeistungsartID">
                            <ComboBox.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <Label Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=SelectedItem.Bezeichnung}"
                                           Margin="0,0,0,0" Padding="0,0,0,0"/>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </ComboBox.Template>
                        </ComboBox>
```