# WPF DataGrid Lookup Column Value

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a DataGrid bound to a table in DataSet A. I'm manually creating the grid columns.

Two of the columns comprise the key into a table in DataSet B and I need to display the (read-only) lookup Name instead of the IDs.

I'm guessing I use a Value Converter of some sort but don't know how to get started.

I saw this: [Lookup-id-control in WPF DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596440/lookup-id-control-in-wpf-datagrid) but 1) I need to specify the combobox's ItemSource in the code and can't figure out how to do so 2) I've got a tuple key 3) it seems there should a more straightforward way to accomplish this.

Thanks!
Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comment, I'm falling back on Plan A which is more model/view friendly.

I think I'm just going about it 'wrong' otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

It hurts that the tables are in different `DataSet`s.  Can you possibly clone the referenced table into `DataSet` A?

If they were in the same `DataSet`, then it would be simple:

1. Create a `DataRelation` between the child table (the one with the foreign key columns) and the parent table (the one containing the lookup name).
2. Create a `DataColumn` in the child table and set its `Expression` to `Parent!Name`.
3. Add the new `DataColumn` to your `DataGrid`.

Comment: Yes, actually, I'm falling back on Plan A which is more model/view friendly. Namely, encapsulating all the data in a class from the datasets. I'm integrating this into an existing WinForms so I guess it will be a little convoluted no matter what I do.

Comment: Well, I don't know about your application, but using foreign-key relations and calculated columns in your `DataSet` isn't convoluted, and works across presentation platforms.  There are a million other good reasons to build a class wrapper for your data, though.